Trying to automate using pyautogui and docker firefox, but can't stick to the constraints of the display
I'm using an M1 MacBook Pro with docker desktop.  So this is a Retina display.
I've deployed the jlesage/firefox image in the following way:
docker run -d \
    --name firefox \
    -p 5800:5800 \
    -p 5900:5900 \
    -e DISPLAY_WIDTH=1024 \
    -e DISPLAY_HEIGHT=768 \
    -e DISPLAY=:0 \
    -v /Users/vw/DEV/docker/scripts:/scripts \
    -e VNC_PASSWORD=password \
    jlesage/firefox

It works fine, I can VNC into it and browse and all.
Next I created a python script with pyautogui to find and click the Facebook button:
import os
import pyautogui
import time

# Ensure the script uses the Docker container's display
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"

# Delay to allow setup
time.sleep(3)

try:
    # Locate the image within the Docker display
    location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Facebook.png', confidence=0.8)

    if location:
        x, y = location
        # Constrain search to 1024x768
        if 0 <= x < 1024 and 0 <= y < 768:
            print(f"Image found at: {location}")
            pyautogui.click(location)
        else:
            print(f"Image found outside bounds (1024x768): {location}")
    else:
        print("Image not found on the screen.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

The error message I get is:
Image found outside bounds (1024x768): Point(x=np.int64(1743), y=np.int64(1145))
so it's not using the display I'm specifying.
I've also exported DISPLAY manually from my terminal.

Where is the Python script running?  If DISPLAY=:0 then I'd normally expect the client to try to use the Unix socket in /tmp/.X11-unix/X0, but that directory doesn't seem to be shared into your Firefox container.  A virtual machine could bundle together a display server, the browser, and the scraper in one package, and you could use more normal tooling with it; would that work better here?

I'm trying to think of the overhead. Not sure if a vm is the right answer.   The overall goal is several open Web pages, interacting at the same time. I can't just start a vm to item a single web page 10 times over.
